# Setting the right truststore in JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss, truststore

I want to send EMails from a JBoss 7 application. The SMTP server needs a TLS connection with a self signed certificate. If I try to send a EMail I get a SSLHandshakeException because the server certificate cannot be checked. To fix this I have add this: http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/29/fixing-pkix-path-building-issues-when-using-javamail-and-smtp/ (putting the SMTP server certificate into a java truststore file)

My problem is now how to set the truststore file to JBoss 7?

I known at stackoverflow and on other forums there are several answer for that propblem. But I didn't found the right.

I have already tried followings:

- adding `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/stewert.c-on/data/projects/keystore/devel.truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456"` to:

  - jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.conf
  - jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/domain.conf
  - jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/appclient.conf
- adding `<jsse keystore-password="123456" keystore-url="/home/stewert.c-on/data/projects/keystore/devel.keystore" truststore-password="123456" truststore-url="/home/stewert.c-on/data/projects/keystore/devel.truststore"/>` to jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

But if I check at runtime the system environment variable with 'System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")' I get in every case null!

My environment:

- Linux
- JBoss 7.1
- JDK 7
- I'm starting JBoss inside of eclipse Juno

Anybody knows what's going wrong? Where must I set the truststore?

Thanks,
Steffen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone asked on the JBoss forum "[javax.net.ssl.trustStore - only way to specify client trust?](https://community.jboss.org/message/749863)", and the answer is basically "yes".

Their approach was to set that in a [`system-properties`](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SystemProperties) element in the server config XML, which seems like the best way to me too. Better than grubbing about in the run configuration files!

Comment: YES! That's it! I'm new with JBoss (switching from glassfish to JBoss currently) and so I wasn't known that I can setting system properties inside the standalone.xml. Thanks a lot!