# Consuming SSL Web Services on JBoss 7

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jboss, jax-ws

I'm running an application in JBoss7 using JAXWS to consume Web Services. However, I have to consume one of these Web Services over SSL.

I can set that up by using `System.setProperty()` for properties like `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, etc. with appropriate passwords set.

This is working, but it doesn't seem very elegant to me. So, my question is: Is there a better way to consume Web Services over SSL?

Comment: Apparently there isn't : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730421/setting-the-right-truststore-in-jboss-7

Comment: What's the problem with inelegant? are you optimizing for clarity, speed, some other thing? What does better look like to you?

Comment: I'm not optimizing anything. I just wanted to know if there was another (maybe better or different) way to did that.